# Quasi-Finite + Affine -> Finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

If $f:X\to Y$ is an affine morphism of schemes, say with $Y$ irreducible, that is quasi-finite - all of the fibers, including the generic fiber, are finite - is it true that $f$ is finite?

If not, what is a good counterexample.

EDIT: I also am requiring that $f$ be closed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $U = \mathbb{P}^1 - \{1\}$ and let $f : U \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be the squaring map $z\mapsto z^2$. Then $f$ is a counterexample. (Note that it is still surjective.)

The point is that "closed" is not sufficient. The property you want is "universally closed", that is, remains closed after any base change.

It is true that quasi-finite + affine + universally closed $\Rightarrow$ finite. (The precise statement is that finite = quasi-finite + proper.)

Comment: Ah, good. I actually have that for the case in which I am interested. I was proving that affine + proper $\Rightarrow$ finite. This question was coming from the fact that the fibers are all finite by a Noether normalization argument, so the morphism is quasi-finite, affine and closed. But in fact it is proper by assumption, so all is well. Thanks again!

Comment: Make sure there is nothing circular in the logic here!

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f\colon \textrm{Spec}\left(k[x,y]/(xy-1)\right) \to \textrm{Spec} \left(k[x]\right)$$ be the projection of the hyperbola onto the affine line. Then, $f$ is quasi-finite, but it is not finite.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. Thanks! I should however have also added that I know $f$ to be closed for the case in which I am interested; the projection from the hyperbola is not closed, of course.